# Violating const correctness: What problems should I expect realistically?

Tags: c++

I want to use a [function parser library](http://warp.povusers.org/FunctionParser/fparser.html) where the member function `FunctionParser::Eval()` is non-const, because it writes an error code to a member variable. I would like to integrate this function parser into a codebase, where this function would get called through a `const` member function of a class holding that function parser, thus violating `const` correctness.

This `const` member function is part of an interface, where the `const`ness makes semantic sense. I *could* change that interface, so that remains an option.
As a test, I used `const_cast` to execute the code violating `const` correctness, which did not cause any errors or failed unit tests (at least not in Debug mode).

Now my question is: What problems down the road should I expect when violating `const` correctness in this case? (And would that ever be worth it?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the object is actually *defined* const, then casting away const-ness to modify the object is undefined behavior.

Consider instead using the `mutable` keyword, which declares an exception to const-ness for a given field; a `mutable` field is *always* non-const even when accessed on an object that is considered const in the current context (including from within const methods).

```
class foo {
private:
    int a;         // cannot be modified on a const foo
    mutable int b; // CAN be modified on a const foo!
};
```

You could use the `mutable` keyword for fields related to error tracking.

Of course, a better pattern would be to throw an error object if an error occurs.  If your API design does not permit this, making the relevant fields mutable is the correct workaround.

Comment: How come I've never even heard of that keyword before?! This worked perfectly, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> What problems down the road should I expect when violating const correctness in this case? (And would that ever be worth it?)

If the object in question was constructed as a `const` object, then you definitely run into undefined behavior. However, if the object was constructed as a non-`const` object, then using `const_cast` to call a non-`const` member function is OK.

Simple example:

```
struct Foo {int f; };

void testFoo(Foo const& foo)
{
   const_cast<Foo&>(foo).f = 10; // Analogous to calling a non-const member function.
}

int main()
{
    Foo obj1 = {20};
    Foo const obj2 = {30};

    testFoo(obj1); // ok. obj1 was constructed as a non-const object.
    testFoo(obj2); // Not ok.  obj2 was constructed as a non-const object.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're *not* violating const-correctness; you're merely bypassing the built-in language checks for it.

Modifying a non-`const` thing is fine, even if you had to cast away some `const`ness somewhere along the way (indeed, this is what `const_cast` is *for*).

This is generally considered to be a dangerous thing to do, though, and dangerous code to write, so you *should* modify your interface or design. (This sounds like a good use case for `mutable`.)

But what runtime *errors* or weirdness can you expect right now? None at all.

Comment: So far, I've only used ```const_cast``` on occasions where I could make sure that the object actually wasn't modified. For example, some MPI functions take non-const void pointers, but then depending on what you do afterwards, you can make sure that the object pointed to is never modified. So that's what my understanding of the use of ```const_cast``` was until now. But this helps to broaden it, thanks :)

Comment: @RL-S Oh yes, that's a common usage of `const_cast`, too, yep. You really only want to be using it when you're forced to, and can guarantee that it's safe regardless of the hack.